# Add corresponding index to array's value

Tags: php

I have an array below here and I need to add the corresponding index to it and change the value of the array.

```
    $colors = array( 
        'name' => 'green',
        'name' => 'red',
        'name' => 'yellow',
        'name' => 'purple',
        'name' => 'marsala',
        'name' => 'blue'
    );
```

expected result:

```
    array(
        'name' => 'green-0',
        'name' => 'red-1',
        'name' => 'yellow-2',
        'name' => 'purple-3',
        'name' => 'marsala-4',
        'name' => 'blue-5'
    );
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Array indexes must be unique.

Comment: To add to the above;  [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)  in PHP.

Comment: _"I have an array below here"_ - so any array that contains only _one_ single item, under the key `name` and with the value `blue` ...? (Because that is what you actually would have with that exact code, because the same array key/index used repeatedly of course overwrites the previous item that was stored under that key/index.)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I understand indexes must be unique. The array I wrote there is just an example. The actual question is "please write a code that will add the corresponding index to each color value (ie. green-0, red-1, yellow-2...)".

Answer (score -1):

Ok I tried this loop and it works :

```
$colors = array('green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'marsala', 'blue');


for($i = 0; $i < count($colors); $i++) {

$colors[$i] = $colors[$i] . '-' . $i;

}
```

the result is good